fetch SSL Errors (Socket hang up, SSL alert number 80, ECONNRESET)
I use Strapi CMS as the backend for an application. Within Strapi I have a custom controller which acts as a middleman endpoint between my application and many WooCommerce Stores' API.
Most of the sites work fine however I have a small number of them (~3-4) that give me persistent errors when fetching the data.
The error returned can vary but it always centers around SSL. Below is an example of the output:
0|app  | Failed to fetch from WooCommerce FetchError: request to https://[...]&page=1&per_page=10 failed, reason: write EPROTO 139879860451264:error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1565:SSL alert number 80
0|app  |     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///home/cms/app-cms/app-cms/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:108:11)
0|app  |     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
0|app  |     at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
0|app  |     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
0|app  |     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
0|app  |     at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
0|app  |     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
0|app  |     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
0|app  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
0|app  |   type: 'system',
0|app  |   errno: 'EPROTO',
0|app  |   code: 'EPROTO',
0|app  |   erroredSysCall: 'write'
0|app  | }
0|app  | Failed to fetch from WooCommerce FetchError: request to https://[...]&consumer_secret=cs_bf89539041f9622ca8628d6fe5e22faf2cd420dd&page=1&per_page=10 failed, reason: write EPROTO 139879860451264:error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1565:SSL alert number 80
0|app  |     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///home/cms/app-cms/app-cms/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:108:11)
0|app  |     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
0|app  |     at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
0|app  |     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
0|app  |     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
0|app  |     at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
0|app  |     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
0|app  |     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
0|app  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
0|app  |   type: 'system',
0|app  |   errno: 'EPROTO',
0|app  |   code: 'EPROTO',
0|app  |   erroredSysCall: 'write'
0|app  | }
0|app  | Failed to fetch from WooCommerce FetchError: request to https://[...]&page=1&per_page=10 failed, reason: write EPROTO 139879860451264:error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1565:SSL alert number 80
0|app  |     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///home/cms/app-cms/app-cms/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:108:11)
0|app  |     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
0|app  |     at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
0|app  |     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
0|app  |     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
0|app  |     at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
0|app  |     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
0|app  |     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
0|app  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
0|app  |   type: 'system',
0|app  |   errno: 'EPROTO',
0|app  |   code: 'EPROTO',
0|app  |   erroredSysCall: 'write'
0|app  | }
Failed to fetch from WooCommerce FetchError: request to https://[...]&page=1&per_page=10 failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
0|app  |     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///home/cms/app-cms/app-cms/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:108:11)
0|app  |     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
0|app  |     at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
0|app  |     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
0|app  |     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
0|app  |     at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
0|app  |     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
0|app  |     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
0|app  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
0|app  |   type: 'system',
0|app  |   errno: 'ECONNRESET',
0|app  |   code: 'ECONNRESET',
0|app  |   erroredSysCall: 'read'
0|app  | }

My Server Config:

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Node 16.20.1
Curl 7.81.0 (latest version according to apt-get upgrade)
node-fetch 3.3.2
npm 8.0.0

API Call JS
This is my current code during debugging:
try {
      const https = require('https');
      const agent = new https.Agent({
        secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method', // or 'TLSv1_3_method'
        keepAlive: true
      });
      const response = await fetch(url, {agent});
      const data = await response.json();

      // Return the WooCommerce data to the client
      ctx.body = data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to fetch from WooCommerce', error);
      ctx.throw(500, 'Failed to fetch data from WooCommerce');
    }

This was my original code:
try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();

      // Return the WooCommerce data to the client
      ctx.body = data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to fetch from WooCommerce', error);
      ctx.throw(500, 'Failed to fetch data from WooCommerce');
    }

I really am not sure where to go from here as some sites we work with are perfectly okay and a small number have these various errors. I'm not able to determine if it is my server config or the remote site either.
Just to add, if I put the whole API url into my browser, I can see the response without issue

@user207421 I understand this however we do not control the remote sites so need to find a solution on our end. After doing some additional debugging I found that specificy ciphers worked for some sites that previously did not work however trying to find a solution that will work for all sites is proving difficult.

If possible I would investigate the situation with plaintext sockets. Cipher suites certainly have nothing to do with this, or any other part of SSL AFACS.

TLS problems are tricky to debug, especially if the server just closes the connection with an internal error alert. It would be helpful if you would actually provide the site in question. If you don't want this check out with SSLabs to see what TLS versions and ciphers it supports and what problems it might show - then compare this to a site known to be working.

These are both cases of SSL alert number 80, which is internal_error inside OpenSSL. Take it up with them.
